# Why is my bash variable executed?

Tags: bash, macos

I've started to write a bash script on my Mac (OS X Yosemite 10.10.5). It has to be the silliest of problems, but I can't figure out what's going on. The script is basically:

```
#!/bin/bash
WORKING_DIR=$(mktemp -d)
```

I was planning to use the `WORKING_DIR` variable for reference later on. The output reads:

```
My-MacBook-Pro:myfolder me$ ./test.sh 
usage: mktemp [-d] [-q] [-t prefix] [-u] template ...
       mktemp [-d] [-q] [-u] -t prefix
```

I don't want `mktemp` to be executed, I'd like for it to be stored in the `WORKING_DIR` variable. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: According to the man page, that usage should not trigger that error. Indeed, it works fine for me on my MacBook.

Comment: When you say you don't want it to be executed, do you mean you don't want it to be displayed?

Comment: Oh, I didn't anticipate it to be executed. But it turns out that's how it supposed to be, so no the code I'm looking at makes more sense. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what command substitution does: it runs the enclosed command *immediately*, and captures the output for use by the enclosing expression (here, it uses it as the value on the right-hand side of the expression).

If you want to defer execution, you need to define a function:

```
working_dir () {
    mktemp -d
}

d1=$(working_dir)
d2=$(working_dir)
# etc
```

Comment: Thanks, @chepner! It makes sense now. :)